# Flowtype: How to properly use $ObjMap for making all functions chainable?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I'm working on some JS package and I want to provide separated flow type definitions as `index.js.flow` because internal behavior is slightly different.

I have this function for create component definition

```js
function defineComponent(name, createFunc);
```

`createFunc` is function which grabs elements and returns object containing particular user defined actions upon that component

so you can call `defineComponent` in this manner:

```js
const loginForm = defineComponent("login form", () => {
  ...
  ...
  return {
    fillUsername: () => { ...doesn't matter what is return type... },
    fillPassword: () => { ...doesn't matter what is return type... }
  };
});
```

and those actions should be chainable, but I don't want to burden user with always mentioning return type within each user defined action. So final chain should look like this:

```js
loginForm
  .fillUsername()
  .fillPassword()
```

So internally `defineComponent` will wrap each user defined action like this for chaining ability:

```js
function defineComponent(..., createFunc) {
  const actions = createFunc(...);

  return actions.map(action => {
    return (...args) => {
      action(...args);
      return actions;
    }
  })
}
```

I already tried this (my whole testing code):

```js
type ComponentType<T> = $ObjMap<T, <V>((V) => any) => V => ComponentType<T>>;

declare function defineComponent<T>(
  name: string,
  createFunc: () => T
): ComponentType<T>;

const Component = defineComponent("foo", () => {
  return {
    fooAction: () => {},
    barAction: () => {}
  };
});

Component.fooAction().barAction()
```

I proceeds with flow's `No errors!` but flow is showing no errors also when I do something like

```
Component.fooAction.barAction()
```

And also VS Code provides no autocompletion above that :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to come up with. The main idea is that we map the original value type `V => mixed` (i.e., a unary function) to `V => T` (i.e., same single argument but now it returns the action map `T`).

```
function chainable<T: { [actionName: string]: Function }>(
  actions: T
): $ObjMap<T, <V>(V => mixed) => (V => T)> {
  return Object.keys(actions).reduce((newActions, actionName) => {
    newActions[actionName] = function(...args) {
      actions[actionName](...args);
      return this;
    }
    return newActions;
  }, {});
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgQxmNAjANgUwB4AVALkQG9EBtNaeMAOTQFt9yBnKAJ0wHMAuuQBi4egkQBfAHwAKOrAQdyxAJTkAJAHlsAKwCyaAA4kANIkIA1OZcQBeaYhYwAHvgAmq+49m2HiNUcKAChEMPDufCgQbiQdXXxoADoAa3wATw55cTAOVSTI9xAIfFlZMHwAdwBBHI5zBQZmNi9-EPCOxAqautoc5vwBe0RQSEUwWSSptG4+PMpQzo7GpT7xgYFJ6dm8gG5FpbDI6NjEKBQYDn3DqQPO45ikbtrxq7uwyXMKSVV9yTvghAlFBEC5hqgMFg8KUqMA4HByLJWo4ACzmbAzRHIyiSKS-AEuJJwuBI-aEjHcUnBQnEilUmnwpFJOn4hkk-K0mb0omM-IsnlwFlk5lcjm84X8zmU1ki6UCplS0lAA)

> **NOTE**: I don't think this is completely typesafe because `this` isn't really of type `T`. But, I don't think that Flow has the complexity to annotate the type of `this` in the `newActions` values. Additionally, this only works if all actions have unary functions for values. Unfortunately, Flow does not have the vocabulary to describe variadic generics (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453 for information on what this means and how it could be used).